# cat [file..] pipe another cat command

Tags: ssh, cat

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@123.45.56.78 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

can someone explain how the quotations works.

From what I understand. I am reading the public key on my disk then piping it to the server, making a directory if it doesn't exist and then... am I using this second concatenation to read from my disk? what is being concatenated?

It get confusing because im used to seeing a file after the cat command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `cat` is able to concatenate files and to print them on the standard output.
When it is invoked without specifying any file or with a `-`, it will read the standard input.
In your command it is used in both the ways.

Step by step:

- The first part of your command (`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) does exactly what you understood: it prints the local file  `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the standard output.
- Then with the symbol `|` you redirect the local standard output as standard input to the following  command (`ssh`).
- The `ssh` command practically will make execute the command inside the string `""` on the remote machine  passing the standard input from the pipe.
- Inside the string:

  - You will create the directory `~/.ssh` and thanks to the option `-p` it will not generate error if the directory just exists.
  - With the operator `&&` you will execute the following `cat` only if the previous `mkdir` exits without errors.
  - The last `cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`  is an invocation of `cat` *without file*. Its output will be appended (if possible) to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` thanks to the redirection operator (`>>`).

---

Notes:

- On many systems it exists the command `ssh-copy-id` to copy the local keys on the remote machine. For more info type `man ssh-copy-id`

  > ssh-copy-id — use locally available keys to authorise logins on a remote machine
- As stated by roalma in the comment the original command line can work or not depending of (restrictive) settings of `ssh` configuration.